# How to implement a Python custom class for outliers removal in pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pipeline

I'm trying to implement a Python custom class for outliers detection and removal by means of the Isolation Forest algorithm. My plan is to use it in a `GridSearchCV` for the hyperparameter tuning of a neural network (regression). Here is my code,

```
class OutlierExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, contamination):
        self.contamination = contamination
        self.mask = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        iso = IsolationForest(contamination = self.contamination)
        yhat = iso.fit_predict(X)
        mask = yhat != -1
        self.mask = mask
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y):
        X = X[self.mask, :]
        y = y[self.mask]
        return (X, y)
```

and the Pipeline

```
estimator = Pipeline([
            ('outliers', OutlierExtractor(0.1)),...
            ]
```

but, running `grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)` it gives the error `transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`.
How to fix it?
Furthermore, it would be very fine being able to perform the tuning on the contamination parameter too.

Answer (score 1):

> running `grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)` it gives the error `transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Despite your not providing the full traceback and the implementation details of your `grid`, I am almost sure the problem is in your `OutlierExtractor.transform` method. It does not conform to scikit-learn transformer API, in which `transform` methods are expected to return only (modified) samples `X`, but you return both `X` and `y`. It is possible though that the error might be caused by other reasons and you might have to resolve them first.

> How to fix it? Furthermore, it would be very fine being able to perform the tuning on the contamination parameter too.

I am afraid it is not possible to set up outlier detection inside scikit-learn pipelines. Fixing `transform` does not help either. Ideally, we would love to have support for the *intermediate* outlier detection inside `Pipeline` (we have `Pipeline.fit_predict` only for the *last* step outlier detection, e.g. when `IsolationForest` is the final predictor in your pipeline). However, this is not implemented yet. If my memory serves me right, there was an issue on this problem in the official github repository of scikit-learn. Also, here is a scikit-learn enhancement proposal [SLEP001](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep001/proposal.html), which touches on outlier detection too.

In order to include `IsolationForest` in model selection, you would want to manually create a parameter grid for it and launch `GridSearchCV` for every entry of this grid. Here is a minimal example:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid  # or ParameterSampler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

X, y = # your data
grid = GridSearchCV( # your model grid search )

isolation_forest = IsolationForest()
isolation_forest_params = {
    'max_features': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    'bootstrap': (False, True),
    'contamination': (0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
}
isolation_forest_param_grid = ParameterGrid(isolation_forest_params)

# Here we split data once but you might want to use
# nested cross-validated grid search instead.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

best_score, best_params = 0, {}
for params in isolation_forest_param_grid:
    isolation_forest.set_params(**params)
    outlier_mask = isolation_forest.fit_predict(X_train)
    X_inliers, y_inliers = X_train[outlier_mask == 1], y_train[outlier_mask == 1]

    grid.fit(X_inliers, y_inliers)
    score = grid.score(X_test, y_test)
    if score > best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_params = grid.best_params_
        # Prepending 'if' prefix so that parameter names will not overlap.
        best_params.update({f'if__{k}': v for k, v in params.items()})
```